# Should I Buy a Cheap Apartment in Manhattan?

Tags: house

I am a recent college graduate and have been offered a job in Manhattan with a salary of $160,000. I am planning on living in the city for at least the next 10 years, and I am trying to decide whether I should buy a home or continue renting. I am considering purchasing a property priced $450,000 or less, but my down payment will be quite low (less than $20,000). As a result, I will need to pay for private mortgage insurance and a larger mortgage. I have noticed that there are some nice studios and one-bedroom apartments in the Upper West Side, Upper East Side, and Midtown areas that cost around $350,000. However, I will be looking at monthly payments of around $5,000 or more. Despite this, I believe that I can manage these payments. What do you recommend that I do? Should I buy or rent? Any advice or feedback is appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of buy/rent calculators out there. Consider also costs additional  to mortgage - taxes, maintenance, monthly HOA dues, etc. NY can be pretty expensive for property ownership.

Comment: $5k a month seems way too high for a 350k mortgage, even including taxes and insurance. If that's true, then it's too much for a 160K income - you'll be "house poor".  If you have 5K in cash flow, rent a cheap place for a few years and save money like mad for a better down payment.

Comment: I know Manhattan is a special case, but in general I recommend against buying housing until you are certain that you will not be relocating in the next few years. Converting the property back into money you can use elsewhere can be a painful process, and a slow one if you want to get a fair price for it.

Comment: I am surprised to learn there are apartments in Manhattan that *only* cost $450,000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you buy the most expensive property you can afford, then you end up in a vulnerable position.  When your paycheck comes in, you pay the mortgage, bills, pay for food, and you have nothing left for savings.  You end up living paycheck-by-paycheck.  If something changes in your life circumstances, and your bills go up or your income goes down, then you have no buffer.

If you go down a bit on the property cost, then you have less mortgage every month.  You can start saving an emergency fund.  When the fund is big enough, you can choose to overpay the mortgage or save even more, or have a few luxuries.  Before long, your life is less stressful, you have more choices, and you're covered if an unexpected bill comes in.

Comment: The situation in the first paragraph is often called "house poor", as in, "poor because you have a house"